# OWIN WebAPI cookie based authentication

Tags: .net, security, cookies, oauth, owin

**Flow: Implicit Grant**

**Background :** The idea is that storing token locally in browser storage is not very good security practice as its pron to XSS attacks. If the token is stored in cookie (httponly) then we can at least mitigate xss.

- Auth Server sends cookie token back to the client (browser) and browser stores the cookie.
- With every API request browser sends Cookie to the WebAPI (which is also auth server) so that it can authenticate.
- No authorization header present in the API request. (i.e. no "bearer" token in header) This is on purpose.

**Problem:** It returns 401 back saying its unauthorized.

If I send the authorization header (with bearer token) then it works. (which I would like to avoid as it defeats the whole purpose)

**AuthServer + WebAPI:**

```
                app.CreatePerOwinContext(Repo.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                // Comment this out to presist the Identity.User in HttpContext Session
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logout"),
                CookieHttpOnly = true,
                CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
                CookieDomain = "mydomain.com",
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
                {
                    OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
                    {
                        if (!IsAjaxRequest(ctx.Request))
                        {
                            ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(MyAuthOptions.JwtOAuthOptions);

            // Setup webapi 
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new MyJwtBearerAuthenticationOptions());
```

Thanks

Comment: Do not use CookieAuth with WebApis. JwtBearer is the correct way to handle this.

Comment: Where would you store JwtBearer token in browser?

Comment: Our samples us ADAL https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/samples/JwtBearerSample/wwwroot/App/Scripts/app.js#L17
http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/02/19/introducing-adal-js-v1/
It looks like it can use localStorage or sessionStorage.
The difference between these and cookies is that cookies are automatically included with requests, where with storage you have to know what you're looking for.

Comment: Problem with storing the token in localstorage or session storage is that its pron to XSS attacks. If the token is stored in cookie with httponly then its safe with XSS attacks.

Comment: What did you end up doing? facing the same problem as you